# Arduino and Decatur Si-2 Radar

Tags: arduino

I got a [Decatur Si-2 Radar](http://ghawgood.com/pdf/radars/si2.pdf) from Ebay. The brochure that I found online has this as the pinout:

```
+12VDC Power        1 (red)
RS232 TX            2 (black)
RS232 RX            3 (green)
Ground(shield)      5 (brown)
Ground              9 (black)
```

How should I hookup my Arduino to get the data, and do you think it will be readable?

Comment: Tell us about what your Arduino says in its manual re its RS232 capabilities.

Comment: @Russell http://lmgtfy.com/?q=arduino+rs232&l=1 now don't be snarky :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Chris's answer is accurate, I'd just like to elaborate on it.

The RS232 standard uses signaling that is -12V to +12V whereas your Arduino "serial port" (aka UART) is 0V to 5V signaling. Furthermore, I believe that the signaling on RS232 is "inverted" with respect to the RS232 standard. For these reasons, in order to connect your Arduino to RS232 devices you must connect through an RS232 Transceiver like the popular MAX232 IC chip.

There are "shields" you can buy for any Arduino that will integrate a chip of that kind and a DB9 connector so you can plug in using a normal serial cable. One example of such a shield would be [this one](http://www.cutedigi.com/product_info.php?products_id=4329), though I'm sure you could find others if you searched.

You still have to watch out for null-modem, cross-over, and the like, but the general idea is you want pin 2 of one side of the interface to connect to pin 3 on the other side and vice versa, and pin 5 (GND) on one side of the interface should be connected to pin 5 on the other side. In summary, the following are the only three signals that are requisite connections for RS232 serial communication between two devices (that are not flow control, which I have actually never seen used in practice).

```
SIDE1            SIDE2
RX               TX
TX               RX
GND              GND
```

You don't need to connect the +12V from the Radar to your Arduino, however if you are powering your Arduino from a 12V supply (through the barrel jack for instance) you could connect that +12V input to the Radar to the VIN pin of the Arduino header to "daisy chain" the power through the Arduino to the Radar..

Answer (score 3):

That appears to use normal RS232 voltage levels, so you would be better off with an older version of an arduino-style board having the 9 pin serial connector and serial level shifter, instead of the USB chip and USB connector that they've had for the past couple of years.

You can still do serial communications with a modern usb-type arduino, but as the atmega chip itself only supports logic level communication, you need a level shifter such as a max232 to talk at rs232 voltage levels.  The level shifter also inverts the sense of the signal to meet the standard.

In terms of software, usually your best bet is to start with a pc terminal program talking to the device by hand, and once you have it sorted out, write your arduino software to do what you were doing manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to make an RS-232 level shifter I have designed a shield you can make yourself with Toner Transfer etching (or whatever method you prefer) which has a MAX232 chip, the capacitors, and a 9-pin D connector.

http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/node/5

It also supports hardware handshaking, but that's not needed in this application as you have no handshake signals to worry about.

Comment: cool! this might have been better suited to as a comment in response to my answer.

Comment: @vicatu - why do you want to delegate this to a comment?  Its certainly not based on your answer but independently re-presents some of the same information in a different format while going beyond yours.